# PHP sessions without cookies

Tags: php, html, session, cookieless

i'm a little lost working without cookies.
I want to create a session passing the SID through the url, but i don't know how to pass and get data from another page.
I've googled a lot but 90% of the examples are with cookies.

Here is what i have.

index.php

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />        
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <a href="index.php?" class="navactive">Index</a>
    <a href="second.php?">Second</a>        

    <form action="access.php" method="POST">
        User: <input type="text" name="user" size="15"/><br>
        Pass: <input type="password" name="pass" size="15"/><br>
        <button type="submit"/>Ok</button>
        <button type="reset"/>Reset</button>
    </form>     

    Logged as: <?php print $_SESSION["name"]; ?>                

</body>
</html>
```

access.php last part

```
........
.......
....

    if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername and redirect to file "second.php"
    ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
    session_name('test');

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $myusername; 

    header("location:second.php?".SID);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Second</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />        
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php?">Index</a>
    <a href="second.php?" class="navactive">Second</a><br>              

    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br>         

    Logged as: <?php print $_SESSION["name"]; ?>                    

</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
    ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
    session_start();
    session_unset();    
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
?>
```

-What do i have to put in "Logged as:" ?. "print $_SESSION["name"];" shows nothing.

-When i log in, i'm redirected to second.php, then i click on any link and the actual logged session dies and SID changes.

thx!

Comment: Cookies are the *sensible* way to pass a session token around. Why are you trying to avoid them?

Comment: Using  "session.use_trans_sid" will cause google to rank your site low. if at all possible you should not use this. Also "$_SESSION["name"]" should be "$_SESSION['name']"... single quote's

Comment: @Quentin i know, but it's for a college exercise and i can't use cookies :(

Comment: nice to see your college has no idea about the real world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just copied your code and tested it out myself. Everything is good but do not use, session_name('test') in your access.php file. Not really sure what that does but it breaks when I have it included. Instead, I used the $_SESSION['name'] without calling the session_name() function and all is working.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php): "you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called)", so it would need to be called on all pages, not just on access.php

Comment: I believe this means, if you use session name you need to call it on all your pages. Not just on your access.php. I recommend to not use it at all. Not what your application is but just remove it and everything will work.

Comment: @JamesLee yeah! session_name() was the problem!
now it's working!
thx

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass anything through a URL you must use the proper syntax:

your.url.com/**?key=value&key2=value2...** and so on

Then to retrieve this data:

`echo $_GET['key']` and `echo $_GET['key2']`